# jenkins pipeline don't pull image in dockerhub

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerhub, linux-containers

jenkins is not pulling images. I am using windows. I am running jenkins as container. I get the following error. I will be glad if you help me.

```
    node {
    def commit_id
    stage('Preparation') {
    checkout scm
    sh "git rev-parse --short HEAD > .git/commit_id"
    commit_id = readFile('.git/commit_id').trim()
    }

    stage('test') {
    def myTestContainer = docker.image('node:4.6')
    myTestContainer.pull()
    myTestContainer.inside {
    sh ' npm install --only=dev '
    sh ' npm '

    }}}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cLHp.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:4.6'
            label 'agent-name'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            // your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `agent-name` with the slave agent name or master as the host for container.